# Transfering files using remote desktop Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, file-transfer

I am trying to transfer files between the two Windows Server 2003 computers. I have already looked online and have selected the Disk Drives option Local Drives in the Local Resources tab. I still cannot see the other machine's drives from either the client or host. I believe this might be due to a security restriction in windows. What are the possible causes of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually just use Copy/Paste rather than looking for the drives in Explorer (as that can be pretty slow). Have you enabled clipboard sharing and tried to Copy/Paste the files.

Comment: It gives me this error: "Cannot copy Test: Windows cannot find '%1!|s!'. Check the spelling and try again, or try searching for the item by clicking the Sate button and then clicking Search."

Comment: @FranzPayer try enabaling Smart Card option in the resources tab.